# Run certain Emacs init commands only in GUI mode

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to run certain commands (from init.el) only when I am in GUI mode and not in terminal mode. I want to set a certain color scheme when I run the GUI version, but that scheme screws up the terminal window's colors pretty badly. I'm looking for some variable/function which would look something like this:

```
(if gui-mode (color-scheme-blah))
```

or:

```
(unless terminal-mode (color-scheme-blah))
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want something like

```
(if window-system (color-scheme-blah))
```

`window-system` can be `'x` or `'mswindows` or possibly even other values, but it's always `nil` when you are on a terminal.

Answer (score 4):

To generally test for a graphic display you want to use the following:

`(display-graphic-p &optional DISPLAY)`

It returns non-nil if DISPLAY is a graphic display. Using for example the `window-system` variable also works, but requires you to refer to a specific environment (such as X or Microsoft Windows).

Answer (score 1):

When using emacsclient and frames GUI or terminal mode is not necessarily a global concept. See the very useful answer to my question at https://superuser.com/questions/165335/how-can-i-show-the-emacs-menu-in-gui-emacs-frames-but-not-in-tty-frames-when-usin .