# Settings only for GUI/Terminal emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to set a theme - one only for terminal, and one only for gui.
I've read this thread: [Run certain Emacs init commands only in GUI mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291136/run-certain-emacs-init-commands-only-in-gui-mode)

Which led me here: https://superuser.com/questions/165335/how-can-i-show-the-emacs-menu-in-gui-emacs-frames-but-not-in-tty-frames-when-usi

And tried to create a function to suit my need.

```
(defun set-frame-theme (frame)
  (let ((want-theme (memq (framep frame) '(x w32 ns))))
    (set-frame-parameter frame '(load-theme '(if want-theme monokai solarized-dark) t))))
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'set-frame-theme)
```

It doesn't work.
I'm trying him to load monokai only if gui, otherwise load solarized-dark.
It does work for the GUI interface, but causes the terminal to seemingly crash.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The emacs lisp function,
    (display-graphic-p) 
Will return true if emacs is running in a GUI.

In your .emacs, add the following to switch between your GUI and terminal themes

```
(if (display-graphic-p)
    (load-GUI-theme)
  (load-Terminal-theme))
```

For easier configuration, I have a simple function called is-in-terminal

```
(defun is-in-terminal()
    (not (display-graphic-p)))
```

you could use this to write an easier to read function

```
(if (is-in-terminal)
    (load-Terminal-theme)
  (load-GUI-theme))
```

For a more complete approach to Terminal Only configuration I have a macro that works just like `progn` but only evaluates the body when Emacs is running without a GUI

```
(defmacro when-term (&rest body)
  "Works just like `progn' but will only evaluate expressions in VAR when Emacs is running in a terminal else just nil."
  `(when (is-in-terminal) ,@body))
```

Example Usage:

```
(when-term
    (load-my-term-theme)
    (set-some-keybindings)
    (foo-bar))
```

This entire block will be totally ignored if running in a GUI, but will run if in Terminal.

All this code was taken from a file in my config, if interested you can check it out here:

https://github.com/jordonbiondo/Emacs/blob/master/Jorbi/jorbi-util.el

Comment: Better than I expected. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried it, and emacs throws an error, saying "Symbol's function definition is void: display-graphics-p". What should I do? I'm using Emacs 24.

Comment: Oops Typo! It should be (display-graphic-p) not (display-graphicS-p) <- note the plural. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

i could solve the issue with:

```
(if (display-graphic-p) (load-theme 'solarized-dark t))
```

the final `t` is to override the confirmation prompt in theme selection.

More [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/draft/manual/html_node/elisp/Custom-Themes.html).

Answer (score 0):

I too had the problem of emacs crashing when running in terminal mode while selecting a color-theme.
I would say this is not an issue with the color-theme but with emacs itself.
Updating to the newest version from HEAD did work for me as of time of this writing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomizingFaces

"If you want different color schemes for different displays, you can customize this as well. In the customize buffer, click the [State] button and choose “Show all display specs”. Now you can use different specs for different displays."

Answer (score -1):

Seems like an issue with the theme itself - nothing more and nothing less. uh well.